# How to parse string in bash by position of starting and ending substring

Tags: bash

For such a log file like this

```
xyz003 2021-12-20T15:08:44+01:00 <local0,debug> my_service: 15:08:44.015 DEBUG ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ MyClass  - Incoming message from service blahblah, headers:{...} payload:(aaa=111, bbb=22222, ccc=333, ddd=44444444444)...
```

I need to parse some things e.g. `ccc`, I need to have the value of it but the value may have variable length and be in variable position in log. So I need to find `ccc=` and return the whole substring to `,`.

I'm not very good in bash scripting. I found only `cut` command or `${string:position:length}` whatever it's called. But I don't know how to tell - `give me everything from position of ccc= to position of first , after that`.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you found `${str:position:length}` reading documentation on [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), then `${str#prefix}`, `${str##prefix}`, `${str%suffix}` and `${str%%suffix}` should be found in the same documentation. (All the above are also covered in [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)).

Comment: In general, it's best to avoid external commands -- `cut`, `sed`, etc -- when you're processing only one line of input at a time. Those tools are faster than native bash code once they're up and running, but starting them up takes a _lot_ of time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with positions to answer your question at all:

```
in='xyz003 2021-12-20T15:08:44+01:00 <local0,debug> my_service: 15:08:44.015 DEBUG ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ MyClass  - Incoming message from service blahblah, headers:{...} payload:(aaa=111, bbb=22222, ccc=333, ddd=44444444444)...'
ccc=${in##*ccc=}  # assign everything after the last "ccc=" to ccc
ccc=${ccc%%,*}    # remove everything after the last , in $ccc
echo "ccc=$ccc"   # ...and you have your output.
```

...or, with regular expressions:

```
if [[ $in =~ ccc=([^,]+), ]]; then
  echo "Found ccc: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```